# Markers (xtick) in PGFplots with higher precision

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

### Graphic

The following MWE shows a figure with all identical axis markers (because the scale is too narrow). The option `xtick` has not "high enough precision".

[image]

### MWE Code

I did not find a suiting example in the [pgfplots package manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) - maybe I did not read/think long enough...
I am not sure what option should be entered in the axis environment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every minor tick]
\addplot coordinates{(0.999,2e-2) (1.001,12) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Similar (but different) questions

- [PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla)
- [Pgfplots with custom axis markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23461/pgfplots-with-custom-axis-markers)
- [specify the step of pgfplots axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/specify-the-step-of-pgfplots-axis)
- [Labels in xtick with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97189/labels-in-xtick-with-pgfplots)
- [xticks steps using Pgfplots / dateplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152430/xticks-steps-using-pgfplots-dateplot)

Comment: I think this could help you, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96347/pgfplots-number-format-on-axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Umz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/41140/umz)'s comment, the following code solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every minor tick,
  x tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=4
  }]
\addplot coordinates{(0.999,2e-2) (1.001,12) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]